# Getting matrixL and matrixU from Eigen::SuperLU?

Tags: c++, eigen

I need to get matrices L and U from Eigen::SuperLU. The method matrixU() returns a UMatrixType. When I call this method, I get the following error

> :cannot convert from `'Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double>,0,int>'` to `'const Eigen::TriangularView<Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double>,0,int>,2> &'`.

If I replace UMatrixType by LUMAtrixType in SuperLUSupport.h, everything compiles but the following code does not give the expected result.

```
using  SpMatc = Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double>>;
Eigen::MatrixXcd matDense = Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(n, n);
matDense(13, 15) = std::complex<double>(5., 3.);
matDense(8, 11) = std::complex<double>(3., 9.);
SpMatc mat = matDense.sparseView();
Eigen::VectorXcd b = Eigen::VectorXcd::Random(n);
mat.makeCompressed();
Eigen::SuperLU<SpMatc> slu;
slu.compute(mat);
Eigen::VectorXcd y = slu.solve(b);  
const auto& matL = slu.matrixL();
const auto& matU = slu.matrixU();
auto permutationMatrixP = Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic>(slu.permutationP());
auto permutationMatrixQ = Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic>(slu.permutationQ());
Eigen::VectorXcd res = permutationMatrixP*b;
matL.triangularView<Eigen::Lower | Eigen::UnitDiag>().solveInPlace(res);
matU.triangularView<Eigen::Upper>().solveInPlace(res);              
Eigen::VectorXcd finalRes = permutationMatrixQ.inverse() * res;         
Eigen::VectorXcd diff = finalRes - y;
Assert::IsTrue(!finalRes.isApprox(y));
```

If I replace  Eigen::SuperLU by Eigen::SparseLU, the result is ok.

Comment: This is expected. SuperLU uses dense matrices, SparseLU uses Sparse matrices, and you are using Sparse matrices. The two types you have are not compatible and cannot be converted from one to the other.

Comment: `SparseLU` is a built-in rewrite of the external SuperLU solver, so better forget about SuperLU and stick with SparseLU.